# Flashing Tkinter Labels

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm a beginner programmer in python and have recently began using tkinter though I have come across a problem which I can't solve.

Basically I have two entry boxes.

- Entry1 = message
- Entry2 = no. of flashes

(This is just an example of what I need.)

All I need is a for loop for a label to pop up and flash `entry1` as many times as `entry2`, yes I realize how to get the entry inputs but I have no idea how to get the label to continuously flash, I have tried `pack_forget` and `.destroy` methods for the label in a loop, but unfortunately it does not display as it almost instantly clears it from the screen again.

Comment: How do you mean for "flash" to be implemented? A background color? The object to grow and shrink quickly? The object to disappear?

Answer (score 7):

The basic idea is to create a function that does the flash (or half of a flash), and then use `after` to repeatedly call the function for as long as you want the flash to occur.

Here's an example that switches the background and foreground colors. It runs forever, simply because I wanted to keep the example short. You can easily add a counter, or a stop button, or anything else you want. The thing to take away from this is the concept of having a function that does one frame of an animation (in this case, switching colors), and then scheduling itself to run again after some amount of time.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Hello, world", 
                              background="black", foreground="white")
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.flash()

    def flash(self):
        bg = self.label.cget("background")
        fg = self.label.cget("foreground")
        self.label.configure(background=fg, foreground=bg)
        self.after(250, self.flash)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What about using Styles? Do you just switch the style of a label every half second or is there a better way?