# How to flash tkinter label limited number of times, and only if conditions are met

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have run the the nice example for a flashing tkinter label given in this answer: [Flashing Tkinter Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419032/flashing-tkinter-labels/21439284#21439284)

However, when I try to add some complexity to it, it fails.

First, I need it to only flash when certain conditions are met (It's an alarm, so, it should only flash in an alarm state, not in normal conditions).

Here is a basic version of what I want to do.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import epics

global root

class AlarmGUI:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.ending = False

        self.crhl = tk.Label(text='CFHT RH',bg='light blue')
        self.crhl.grid(row=1, column=2, 
                        padx=20, pady=20, sticky=tk.W)
        self.crhw = tk.Label(text='something',font=("Helvetica", 25,"bold"),bg='light blue')
        self.crhw.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=tk.W)

        self.cfht()

    def flash(self):
        bg = self.crhw.cget('background')
        fg = self.crhw.cget('foreground')
        self.crhw.configure(background=fg,foreground=bg)
        self.crhw.after(1000,self.flash)  

    def cfht(self):
        #This reads in the value that is being tested
        crh = epics.caget('ws:wsHumid')    #Read in CFHT Relative Humidity

        #Here, I display the value 'crh'
        self.crhw.grid(row=2, column=2,sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.crhw.configure(text=crh,fg='Red',bg='Gray')

        #Now I need to determine if the value crh is in an alarm state
        if (crh > 85):  #If the value is over 85, I need the label to flash.
          self.crhw.flash()

        #Then this keeps checking the humidity value
        self.crhw.after(30000,cfht)

def main():
    global root

    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = AlarmGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have also tried to make the flash function only flash a certain number of times. When I say this (below), it does not flash.  It only prints to the screen 30 times, and then takes like 30 seconds before the gui appears on the screen, and does not flash:

```
def flash(self,count):
        bg = self.crhw.cget('background')
        fg = self.crhw.cget('foreground')
        self.crhw.configure(background=fg,foreground=bg)
        count +=1
        if (count < 31):
             print count, bg, fg
             self.crhw.after(1000,self.flash(count)) 

#And I call it with something like 
self.flash(0) #to initialize the count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. You need to remember that `after` requires a *reference* to a function. When you do something like `after(..., self.flash(count))` you are *calling* the function before calling `after`. Or, more precisely, you're calling it 31 times in rapid succession, each time giving the result (`None`) to `after`, to create 31 jobs that do nothing.

`after` conveniently allows you to include additional parameters to be included in the thing you're calling:

```
self.crhw.after(1000, self.flash, count)
```

### An OO approach

This is a perfect time to use python's object oriented nature. You can create your own label class that has a `flash` method, so you don't have to add the flashing code to your main app. This also makes it really easy to have as many flashing labels as you want.

```
class FlashableLabel(tk.Label):
    def flash(self,count):
        bg = self.cget('background')
        fg = self.cget('foreground')
        self.configure(background=fg,foreground=bg)
        count +=1
        if (count < 31):
             self.after(1000,self.flash, count)
```

You would use it just like a normal `Label`:

```
self.crhw = FlashableLabel(...)
```

And you can flash it like this:

```
self.crhw.flash(0)
```

Comment: "have as many flashing labels as you want"  That's exactly what I need.  I have several weather sensors I've got to monitor.  And it works great with the `if` statement to trigger the flashing, or not.